# How can I set up load-balancing with Tomcat 7 on OpenShift?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, load-balancing, openshift, session-replication

I've been testing OpenShift for a while and I'm very happy with the service. There's one problem that I haven't solved yet, and I can't find much information about how to do it.
I want to enable session replication with Tomcat 7, but it seems they only support load balancing with JBoss AS7.

But I want to use Tomcat. Is there any way to get it running with session replication?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you look in the OpenShift github repo at the JBOSS AS cartridge. This opens ports for clustering. You are basically going to have to write your own downloadable cartridge that opens ports for tomcat to cluster. It would also be part of a scalable application

https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-jbossas

Here is the cartridge writers guide:

http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_cartridge_developers_guide.html